# Spring JPA relations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have a project that is pretty much one of those apps that keeps track of the movies and TV shows you watch. I have a `MovieDAO`, `TvshowDAO`, `CommentDAO`, `RatingDAO`, `PersonalityDAO`, and a `UserDAO`.
It is supposed to function such that a user can make a comment and give ratings, so both `RatingDAO` and `CommentDAO` have a relationship to the user. Now, each comment (and each rating) is on a movie *OR* a TV show *OR* a personality.
What's the best way to map this? Put three relations in the comment and rating to each individual one, or is it possible to put something like a private Object target and map it to a movie *OR* a TV show *OR* a personality?
I'm quite stuck on how to do this. What's the best way?

**EDIT**: relations as in `@ManyToOne` personality, `@ManyToOne` movie, and same in TV show and only fill one

Comment: Define relation on NON COMMENT SIDE

Comment: what do you mean? put the relation in only one side? that wont work, relations are bi directional, no?

Comment: can be, does not have to be.